# Metaio 6.0.2.1 broken?

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, metaio

I have to finish a project I got assigned to using Metaio SDK 6.0.2.1.

But the SDK seems to be broken.

When I launch an Activity that extends `ARViewAcitvity` I get this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mypackagename.ar.MyARActivity

Launching "normal" activities however works just fine.

Comment: is this question solved?

Comment: Did you add the metaioSDK library (metaiosdk.jar file) to your project?